# GoLang and MySQL DB

Tags: go, mysql-connector

Is there a simpler way of executing MySQL commands in Go using the `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` package?

Essentially this is the current command I am using:

```
db.Exec("INSERT INTO table1 (id, title, name, dob, address, email, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", id, title, name, dob, address, email, notes)
```

And how I'm using this command would be:

```
var people []people

for _, person := range people {
     db.Exec("INSERT INTO table1 (id, title, name, dob, address, email, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", person.id, person.title, person.name, person.dob, person.address, person.email, person.notes)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "simpler"?

Comment: If you don't want to write SQL by hand and use that together with `database/sql` then you could look for 3rd party ORMs.. not that I would recommend using an ORM but that seems to be the default path for people who consider plain SQL to be too much of a hassle.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say if there was a _cleaner_ way of doing this command or is this the right way to go about doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by `cleaner way`?

Comment: You might wanna do something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/0yf9O4Zhxin to avoid the unnecessary back-and-forth between your app and the db.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to improve about this code?

Answer (score 0):

https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#NamedExec makes it slightly better. It could be, something like:

```
result, err := db.NamedExec(`INSERT INTO table1 (id, title, name, dob, address, email, notes) VALUES (:id, :title, :name, :dob, :address, :email, :notes)`,
person)
```

Do have a look at my [model.go example](https://github.com/kaihendry/GoApiTutorial/blob/master/model.go) for further details.